# Getting CORS errors on HTTP Post call on frontend

Tags: c#, angular, api, asp.net-core, cors

I wrote an Asp.Net Core api and so far it has been working great, however when I try to send a post request it gives me `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44339/api/drawing/checkout' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have CORS enabled on my backend(startup.cs) like so :

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                      .AllowCredentials()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
```

and  `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);`

I've already wasted a couple of days on this, my GET requests work, as well as my POST requests using Insomnia. Could someone please help me with the Angular part? here's the code I have

On drawing.service.ts:

```
test(param) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/checkout', param, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },withCredentials:true
    });
  }
```

And on my component ts:

```
test() {
      let stringfiedArray = JSON.stringify(this.viewerPerm);
      console.log(stringfiedArray);
      this.drawingSearchService.test(stringfiedArray).subscribe();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share an example URL of your Insomnia request?

Comment: URL:https://localhost:44339/api/drawing/checkout, using NTML authentication, sending JSON as body, header is Content-Type application/json

Comment: As I suspected. You need to configure your API URL in the CORS config. Add `https://localhost:44339` to your CORS policy origin and try again.

Comment: You can add multiple origins in your configuration.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Does your request headers contain following? 

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.other.com 
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`

Comment: Add the above-mentioned options in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proxy.conf.json file on your Angular project including the following content

```
{
"/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:4200",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": ""
  }
}
```

}

Where you call the service you will reference the proxied api as follow:

```
this.http.get(`api/checkout`);
```

remember to use **`** character and not single quotes.

When you run your application be sure to add the proxy file

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

[**GUIDE**](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85)

On the backend, for internal use only, try setting it as follow

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, but it won't do anything(won't even hit the a breakpoint on the first line of my api), chrome's network tab says the request status is "pending"

Comment: Your api is giving back results in isolation?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am going to assume that your current code is working fine with another API service, and does POST requests just fine. I hope you have tested your front end code for sure, and have isolated the problem is only with your API server.

Second, instead of a named policy, try using default policy, just to see if that makes a difference. it would look like this.

```
    //lets add some CORS stuff 
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
```

and later, in Configure,

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(); //it may not matter, but try to put cors between routing and auth.

    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Hey, i tried your suggestion and it didn't work.Actually, i'm not sure of where my problem is, as i can make get calls normally, but not post.Could you take a look at my OP and see if you can spot anything off in my front end?

Comment: if this did not work, then, I am convinced, the issue is with your front end. if I were you, I would do a basic POST test. build a simple POST endpoint on your API server. something takes as simple string as its body and returns that string. then, on your front end app, make a call to this test endpoint using the standard, JavaScript fetch library. if this works, at least you will know that CORS is setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44339/api/drawing/checkout' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

A CORS preflight request using the HTTP `OPTIONS` method  is used to check whether the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers.

And the `OPTIONS` requests are always anonymous, you mentioned that you enabled NTML authentication, which would cause server not correctly respond to the preflight request.

For more information about "CORS preflight request", please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request

If you'd like to run your app(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, to fix this issue, you can try to enable anonymous authentification to allow anonymous access.

Besides, if you host your app(s) on IIS server, to fix this issue, you can install [IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-in-iis) and configure CORS for the app.